# Twitter Bootstrap responsive navbar breaks body when mobile layout is triggered

Tags: google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am a long time silent member of SO. I have always found the answers I needed up to now, hence my very first post! I cannot seem to find a solution to this issue related to twitter bootstrap.

It's a very simple example of google maps integration with the fixed top navbar layout.  Everything works as expected on a desktop browser. Whenever I resize the browser window bootstrap switches to mobile layout and the expand/collapse button shows up. That works well except for the fact that my map container breaks as bootstrap seems to add some padding around the map layer.   I am a new member and it won't let me attach screenshots, but I hope you get and idea by checking the site URL below. Simpy shrink the browser window and you'll see what I am talking about.

I have tested it on Android emulator as well with same results.

[Site URL](http://arielfaur.host-ed.me/work/testmaps/gmaps.html)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be great if the full working code is shared...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add this to your css

```
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
position: fixed;
}
```

I saw that it was

```
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
position: static;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! it's getting closer but still some funny behavior. the map expands in height but not in width and the navbar is partially hidden when shrinking the browser. i created a css override, could you look at it ?

Comment: it works! i had to add another rule to correct margins. so in short there are two overrides to fix it `body { padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;}` and `.navbar-fixed-top { position: fixed; margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0;}` thanks again for your help!